# How to change breadboard power supply output voltage?

Tags: power-supply, breadboard, 5v, 3.3v

I recently bought a 3.3/5v power supply [like this.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010UJFVTU) I'm powering it with a fresh 9 volt battery and 9 volt to barrel connector cable. Right now, it's on 3.3 volt mode, and I have no idea how to switch it to 5 volt mode. All the videos I've seen on how to use it don't describe very well how to change the voltage.

Comment: You move the jumper to the 5 V setting.

Comment: @winny Thats that im confused about, what is the other end of the jumper supposed to be connected to?

Comment: Nothing. Look up how jumpers work in general and you’ll get the idea.

Comment: I looked it up and realized jumpers diddnt mean jumper wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a technical document about the device.](http://www.handsontec.com/dataspecs/mb102-ps.pdf)

Basically you just put the 2 jumpers on the 5V position (bridge the leftmost 2 pins on both jumpers).

[image]